# kendo UI not supported jquery 1.10.1 version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI controls  in my application.
For kendo UI controls accessing with jquery 1.8.3 version and lower versions.
can we access with jquery 1.10.1 version?

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI seems to work fine with that jQuery version:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/APAPaqAB/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

As per Kendo UI Site:

[jQuery version](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#jquery-version)

The current official version of Kendo UI requires jQuery 1.9.1. There are occasions in which a new jQuery version is released, which introduces breaking changes and is not compatible with existing Kendo UI versions. In such cases we recommend using the previous jQuery version until the next official Kendo UI release that resolves the problems. We normally do not change the jQuery version that is shipped with Kendo UI for service packs. We can do this for major releases. The following list provides compatibility information about previous major Kendo UI releases:

```
Kendo UI 2013.3.1119 (Q3 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1 (works also with 1.10.x and 2.0.x)
Kendo UI 2013.2.716 (Q2 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1
Kendo UI 2013.1.319 (Q1 2013) - jQuery 1.9.1
Kendo UI 2012.3.1114 (Q3 2012) - jQuery 1.8.2
Kendo UI 2012.2.710 (Q2 2012) - jQuery 1.7.1
Kendo UI 2012.1.322 (Q1 2012) - jQuery 1.7.1
Kendo UI 2011.3.1129 (Q3 2011) - jQuery 1.7.1
```

There should be no problem to use another minor jQuery version instead of the specified above, e.g. 1.7.2 instead of 1.7.1.